# Devise loses session after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, session-timeout

I have a rails 4 app where I am using devise for authentication and it works perfectly. My only problem is that it loses the session of a user after I deploy it on the server and the users have to sign in again.

If I just do a restart of nginx/passenger (which I am using for my app) it doesn't loses it. 
When I am deploying my app I am losing it. For deploying I am also wipe out all the database automatically and my deployment script runs the seeds file which it also generates the users.

We are currently developing the app so this kind of behavior is acceptable for now, but in the 
future when the app will be ready, we won't do it like this way (of course!).

So is this an issue due to the reseeding or I should check something else? I see that the encrypted password changes everytime I run the wipe out/seed action, does this have to do with the losing of user session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the following:

Everytime some user changes his password, devise automatically signs_out him.

So, basically by reseeding the data, the password is recalculated (even though the password is the same, the new encrypted password is different from the old one). So the devise will automatically sign_out the user, because it seems like the password is changed (based on the different encrypted_password field).

I managed to bypass this behavior, by specifically setting up the encrypted_password in the seeds.rb file and bypassing the validation.

Answer (score 8):

You should never wipe out a database during deployment. Imagine that your app is running and you have hundreds of users. Now you make some changes in the code and do a deploy. *POOF* all your data and users are gone! Certainly this is not what you want.

Secondly, users getting logged out when you wipe out the database could be due one of the following reasons:

- Are you seeding users with the same ID? If the user ID changes when you re-seed, it will cause users to be logged out
- Are you storing sessions in the database using `config.session_store :active_record_store` instead of using cookies? In this case, wiping out the database will delete the sessions table and log out all users
- Rails 4 uses an encrypted cookie store by default. Make you sure you're not changing your application's `config.secret_token` when re-deploying, in case its getting loaded from the database

Ultimately, wiping out the database is the sole reason why your users are getting logged out, and that is a bad practice. So the most important thing to fix is **do not wipe data during deployments**.

Comment: Our app is under development, when it will be in production we won't do it like this, we will just add migrations (I wrote it in my message). We are changing/testing too much so  it is necessary in this early phase. The user's id are specifically defined in the seed so the users have the same id every time we are reseeding the database. We don't change secret_token and we are using the default of the devise. So why is this happening?

Comment: @JohnDel how about the other two suggestions? sessions table and user ID?

Comment: We are using :cookie_store as a session_store (inside the initializer) and the users have the same ids before and after the wiping out/reseeding.

Comment: on rails 4 should check also that secret_key_base does not change

Answer (score 2):

> If I just do a restart of nginx/passenger (which I am using for my
>   app) it doesn't loses it. When I am deploying my app I am losing it.
>   For deploying I am also wipe out all the database automatically and my
>   deployment script runs the seeds file which it also generates the
>   users.

If you generate new users, the old ones will lose their sessions.

This is because the values of the new users will be different. For example, they might not have a remember token set, or if the session_id uses the values of `user.created_at` or `user.token_generated_at` they will be different every time you drop and recreate your database.

Comment: "If you generate new users, the old ones will lose their sessions". Why? Aren't the sessions stored in the browser? I don't store them in the database.

Comment: A session is user specific. If you create a new user, it will be a different user even tough the email adress might be the same.

Comment: All the user rows are the same (id, email etc.). The only thing that changes in the database is the stored encrypted password (even though I am using the same password, the devise encrypts it in a new string). Why? I am storing the session in cookie.